# How to read a large file line by line?

Tags: php

I want to read a file line by line, but without completely loading it in memory.

My file is too large to open in memory, and if try to do so I always get out of memory errors.

The file size is 1 GB.

Comment: see my answer at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231547/export-simple-excel-data-into-mysql-using-php/13231633#13231633)

Comment: You should use `fgets()` without `$length` parameter.

Answer (score 856):

You can use the `fgets()` function to read the file line by line:

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: How does this account for the `too large to open in memory` part?

Comment: You are not reading the entire file in memory. The max memory needed to run this depends on the longest line in the input.

Comment: For a way to read the file while uploading it, try the answer to [How does one upload a .txt file in PHP and have it read line by line on another page?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13176687/662581)

Comment: @Brandin - Moot - In those situations, the asked question, which is to read a file LINE BY LINE, does not have a well-defined result.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Then define what should happen. If you want you can just print the message "Line too long; giving up." and that is a well-defined result too.

Comment: Can a line contain a boolean false? If so then this method would stop without reaching the end of file. The Example #1 on this URL http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php suggests that fgets sometimes can return boolean false even though end of file has yet not been reached. In the comment section on that page people report that fgets() doesn't always return correct values, so it's safer to use feof as the loop conditional.

Comment: @cjohansson is correct that FALSE is returned on EoF but also on error by fgets. Though -reader beware that- feof also returns FALSE on error as well as not being at EoF yet. Checking both the fgets !== FALSE and, after exiting the while, ensure feof === TRUE may be preferable.

Answer (score 142):

```
if ($file = fopen("file.txt", "r")) {
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        # do same stuff with the $line
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but: using while(!feof($file)) isn't recommended. [Have a look here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: BTW: "If there is no more data to read in the file pointer, then FALSE is returned." http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php ... Just in case

Comment: `feof()` doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score 138):

You can use an object oriented interface class  for a file - **SplFileObject** http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgets.php (PHP 5 >= 5.1.0)

```
<?php

$file = new SplFileObject("file.txt");

// Loop until we reach the end of the file.
while (!$file->eof()) {
    // Echo one line from the file.
    echo $file->fgets();
}

// Unset the file to call __destruct(), closing the file handle.
$file = null;
```

Comment: much cleaner solution. thanks ;) haven't used this class yet, there are more interesting functions here to explore: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php

Comment: Thanks. Yes, for example you can add this line before while   
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE);   
in order to drop newlines at the end of a line.

Comment: Thanks! Also, use `rtrim($file->fgets())` to strip trailing newlines for each line string that is read if you don't want them.

Comment: @Chud37 yes there is: https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.eof.php

Comment: Even shorter: `foreach (new SplFileObject('file.txt') as $line) echo $line`

Answer (score 97):

If you want to use `foreach` instead of `while` when opening a big file, you probably want to encapsulate the `while` loop inside a Generator to avoid loading the whole file into memory:

```
/**
 * @return Generator
 */
$fileData = function() {
    $file = fopen(__DIR__ . '/file.txt', 'r');

    if (!$file) {
        return; // die() is a bad practice, better to use return
    }    
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        yield $line;
    }

    fclose($file);
};
```

Use it like this:

```
foreach ($fileData() as $line) {
    // $line contains current line
}
```

This way you can process individual file lines inside the foreach().

Note: Generators require >= PHP 5.5

Comment: This should be an accepted answer instead. Its hundred times faster with generators.

Comment: And waaay more memory-efficient.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac: Can you explain why this solution is more memory-efficient? For instance, in comparison to the `SplFileObject` approach.

Comment: Not sure what Tachi and The Onin's comments are comparing against, but I ran this against a 90MB text file, compared with codadict's method and found this to be 44% slower and use the same amount of memory. (ran on PHP 7.3)

Comment: @Tachi you are probably confusing something. This solution is neither "faster" or "slower" than the code in the accepted answer, let alone "hundred times". That's just a solution that allows one to use foreach instead of while, which *looks nicer* but inside it is using **exactly the same `while` loop** used in other answers

Answer (score 37):

There is a `file()` function that returns an array of the lines contained in the file.

```
foreach(file('myfile.txt') as $line) {
   echo $line. "\n";
}
```

Comment: The one GB file would be all read into memory and converted to a more than one GB array... good luck.

Comment: This was not the answer to the question asked, but it does answer the more common question many people have when looking here, so it was still useful, thanks.

Comment: file() is very convenient for working with small files. Especially when you want an array() as the end result.

Comment: this is a bad idea with bigger files as whole file is being read to an array at once

Comment: This breaks badly on large files, so it is exactly the method that does not work.

Comment: Keep in mind that if a file is 1GB large, the array will actually be significantly large.

Comment: Does anyone need to point out again that this method will not work on large files? We have already acknowledged why and where this is useful.

Answer (score 33):

The obvious answer wasn't there in all the responses.
PHP has a neat streaming delimiter parser available made for exactly that purpose.

```
$fp = fopen("/path/to/the/file", "r");
while (($line = stream_get_line($fp, 1024 * 1024, "\n")) !== false) {
  echo $line;
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This way I got the newline from the end of each line included.

Comment: @ValterEkholm Yes, the newline from the end of each line becomes another normal character, as the delimiter is not the newline anymore.

Comment: Use "r" and not "r+" that also requests write mode

Answer (score 31):

Use buffering techniques to read the file.

```
$filename = "test.txt";
$source_file = fopen( $filename, "r" ) or die("Couldn't open $filename");
while (!feof($source_file)) {
    $buffer = fread($source_file, 4096);  // use a buffer of 4KB
    $buffer = str_replace($old,$new,$buffer);
    ///
}
```

Comment: this deserves more love, as it will work with huge files, even files that have no carriage returns or exceedingly long lines...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the OP didn't really care about actual lines and just wanted to e.g. serve a download. In that case, this answer is just fine (and what most PHP coders would do anyway).

Comment: Sir, How will you locate the file inside the fopen() by the way? Assuming we need to specify the url for opening!

Answer (score 25):

```
foreach (new SplFileObject(__FILE__) as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Comment: Memory efficient compared to `file()`.

Answer (score 9):

One of the popular solutions to this question will have issues with the new line character. It can be fixed pretty easy with a simple `str_replace`.

```
$handle = fopen("some_file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Using `rtrim()` is shorter for the same purpose :) And it is cross-platformed.

Answer (score 9):

This how I manage with very big file (tested with up to 100G). And it's faster than fgets()

```
$block =1024*1024;//1MB or counld be any higher than HDD block_size*2
if ($fh = fopen("file.txt", "r")) { 
    $left='';
    while (!feof($fh)) {// read the file
       $temp = fread($fh, $block);  
       $fgetslines = explode("\n",$temp);
       $fgetslines[0]=$left.$fgetslines[0];
       if(!feof($fh) )$left = array_pop($lines);           
       foreach ($fgetslines as $k => $line) {
           //do smth with $line
        }
     }
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: how do you ensure that 1024*1024 block doesn't break in the middle of the line?

Comment: @user151496 easy!! count... 1.2.3.4

Comment: @OmarElDon what do you mean?

Comment: @user151496 I think the `$left` variable is there for that purpose. Buffering is usually faster so this is probably a better solution if you don't mind the added complexity.

Answer (score 8):

Be careful with the 'while(!feof ... fgets()' stuff, fgets can get an error (returnfing false) and loop forever without reaching the end of file.  codaddict was closest to being correct but when your 'while fgets' loop ends, check feof; if not true, then you had an error.

Answer (score 8):

SplFileObject is useful when it comes to dealing with large files.

```
function parse_file($filename)
{
    try {
        $file = new SplFileObject($filename);
    } catch (LogicException $exception) {
        die('SplFileObject : '.$exception->getMessage());
    }
    while ($file->valid()) {
        $line = $file->fgets();
        //do something with $line
    }

    //don't forget to free the file handle.
    $file = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo '<meta charset="utf-8">';

$k= 1;
$f= 1;
$fp = fopen("texttranslate.txt", "r");
while(!feof($fp)) {
    $contents = '';
    for($i=1;$i<=1500;$i++){
        echo $k.' -- '. fgets($fp) .'<br>';$k++;
        $contents .= fgets($fp);
    }
    echo '<hr>';
    file_put_contents('Split/new_file_'.$f.'.txt', $contents);$f++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the fgets() function in combination with a loop:

```
$filename = 'path/to/your/file.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');

if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // Process the current line
        echo $line;

        // You can perform any desired operations on the line here
        // For example, you can parse and extract data from each line

        // Proceed to the next line
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: What what many answers above show already.

Answer (score -9):

Function to Read with array return

```
function read_file($filename = ''){
    $buffer = array();
    $source_file = fopen( $filename, "r" ) or die("Couldn't open $filename");
    while (!feof($source_file)) {
        $buffer[] = fread($source_file, 4096);  // use a buffer of 4KB
    }
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: This would create a single array of more than one GB in memory (good luck with it) divided not even in lines but in arbitrary 4096 character chunks. Why on earth would you want to do that?