# Echo file content based on separator

Tags: php

I have a txt file with lines in this format

```
this is a name|this is a type|this is a description
this is a name|this is a type|this is a description
this is a name|this is a type|this is a description
```

I need to access those lines and echo them like this:

```
<li type="this is a type" description="this is a description">this is a name</li>
```

I have no idea how to approach this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't write code for you without you having provided an example of what you've tried, but in this case it's pretty basic.

Use PHP's `file` function to read a file into an array (line by line), then use `explode` to break that line up:

```
<?php

$contents = file('yourfile.txt');

foreach($contents as $eachline) {
    list($name, $type, $description) = explode("|", $eachline);
    echo '<li type="' . $type . '" description="' . $description . '">' . $name . '</li>';
}

?>
```

PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to read every line of the file.

[How to read a file line by line in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

After that explode the string by the pipe symbol `$out = explode("|", $string);`

after that you have an array and you can access the values with `$out[0];` for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is easypeasy:

```
$parts = explode("|", $line);
$out = "<li type='$parts[1]' description='$parts[2]'>$parts[0]</li>"
```

Comment: Actually `$parts[1] $parts[2] $parts[0]`