# How to read multiple line from file and split it to array in php

Tags: php

I hava a file that contains :

```
ali 123456
vali 154667
```

I want to read this file and split into array like this:

```
$array[0][0]=ali 
$array[0][1]=123456
$array[1][0]=vali
$array[1][1]=154667
```

I searched about this and saw w3schools documents, But I can't read my wanted!
Please show me How should I do it!

Best Regard, Minallah Tofig

Comment: Make an attempt here a link for a start http://php.net/manual/ro/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, initialize the array:

```
$myArray = array();
```

open the file:

```
$file = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
```

iterate the file line by line

```
while (!feof($file)) {
   $line = fgets($file);
   $myArray[] = explode(' ', $line);
}
```

close the file

```
fclose($file);
```

`$myArray` contains your result

Comment: Thank You, Your Answer Is My Wanted!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the php function file() to read the file line by line into an array. Then you have to loop through it and explode() by the white space.

```
$array = file('file.txt.');
foreach($array as $key => $line) {
    $array[$key] = explode(" ", $line);
}
```

http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php) explains how you read a file line by line in PHP. The top and bottom of it is:

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
    }
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}  
fclose($handle);
```

Now in your case, you've got a structured line. Namely.

```
<name><space><value>
```

I would strongly, strongly argue against using a multi dimensional array for this. Instead, go for an OOP based solution. First, define a class.

```
class Person {
    protected $name;
    protected $code;

    function __construct($line) {
        // Split and load.
    }
}
```

Then you can create an array of `Person` objects.

```
$people = array();
```

Then cycle through each line and create a `Person` object.

```
while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $people[] = new Person($line);
}
```

Now you've got all the pieces of the puzzle, it's up to you to put them all together!

Comment: Why are you still using old PHP4 functions?

Comment: What is the logic behind creating a class and create for each line a new class object?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I just pulled from the other answer; didn't want to replicate answers. I'll upvote yours for using the later code. And the logic is, it's much, much easier to conceptualise. It's better to have a list of `Person` objects rather than an ugly, multi-dimensional array of values.

Comment: Well, you have to weigh the cost and use-factor of this class. The cost factor of an 'ugly, multi-dimensional array' (I think it's better than using a class for something you wouldn't need one) is much less than building a class. @christopher

Comment: But the next guy turning up will have a much easier time with `$person->getName()` then `$array[$key][0][0]`. It's not just about the efficiency of the code. It's about making maintainable code. Obviously it's just two different approaches to development. @CharlotteDunois