# Foreach Loop only loops once

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to make many requests to my website, using proxies and headers in PHP, and grab a proxy line by line from a text file to use in the file_get_contents, however I have 3 proxies in the text file (one per line) and the script is only using one, then ending. (I am executing it from command line)

```
<?php
$proxies = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents("proxies.txt"));
foreach($proxies as $cpr0xy) {
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => "tcp://$cpr0xy",
        'request_fulluri' => true,
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
         "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36\r\n" 
    ), );
$rqcon = stream_context_create($aContext);
$destc = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/file.php", False, $rqcon);
echo $destc;
 } ?>
```

Right now its only using the first proxy and it is returning the value correctly, however then the script stops. My goal is for it to endlessly make requests until it runs out of proxies in proxies.txt

Comment: Try: `$proxies = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents("proxies.txt"));` does that do the trick for you? Also do a `print_r($proxies);`

Comment: Have you checked that `$proxies` has 3 elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a file line by line in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

Comment: Rizier123's solution worked, thanks for answering

Comment: @CarlosAllende Nice that it works for you! Wrote a answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$proxies = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents("proxies.txt"));
```