# get the first 3 lines of a text file in php

Tags: php, text, lines

I am developing a website in PHP, and I must include in the index the first 3 lines of a text file in PHP. How can I do that?

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("text.txt");
//echo the first 3 lines, but it's wrong
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: use `file()` and get indices `0-2`

Comment: you can get idea from there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php You would get more help if you google it.

Comment: How? can you give me the correct code? I guess it isn't very difficult, but I'm not good in opening/editing/reading files in PHP

Comment: There are probably a hundred questions on here that are extremely similar to this. Did you try searching the site?

Comment: How big is the file? If it is large then you should probably avoid using `file()`. It will read the *entire file* into memory. It is a little over-kill just to get 3 lines.

Answer (score 12):

Even more simple:

```
<?php
$file_data = array_slice(file('file.txt'), 0, 3);
print_r($file_data);
```

Comment: This reads the ENTIRE file into array elements, then isolates the first three elements.  Is it concise? Yes.  Is it lean/efficient? No.

Comment: This works, but in my case (for exemple) i have to read a file with millions of line (4/5Gb CSV) so really not a recomended option

Answer (score 9):

Open the file, read lines, close the file:

```
// Open the file for reading
$file = 'file.txt';
$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');

// Handle failure
if ($fh === false) {
    die('Could not open file: '.$file);
}
// Loop 3 times
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    // Read a line
    $line = fgets($fh);

    // If a line was read then output it, otherwise
    // show an error
    if ($line !== false) {
        echo $line;
    } else {
        die('An error occurred while reading from file: '.$file);
    }
}
// Close the file handle; when you are done using a
// resource you should always close it immediately
if (fclose($fh) === false) {
    die('Could not close file: '.$file);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `file()` function returns the lines of a file as an array. Unless the file is huge (multiple megabytes), you can then use `array_slice` to get the first 3 elements of this:

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
$first3 = array_slice($lines, 0, 3);
echo implode('', $first3);
```

Comment: This reads the ENTIRE file into array elements, then isolates the first three elements.  Is it concise? Yes.  Is it lean/efficient? No.

Comment: @mickmackusa Depends on how big the file is. If you want the first 3 lines of a 100-line file, this is fine. If it's a megabyte, there are better ways.

Comment: _"This reads the ENTIRE file into array elements, then isolates the first three elements."_ is a fact. Is it worthwhile to worry about the overhead of this technique?  That depends, yes.  I am just bringing awareness to researchers that may choose the "shorter copy-pasta" which may not be ideal for their project.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck. @mickmackusa

Comment: Computers are really fast and memory is cheap. 99% of the time it's not a concern. Beginners usually won't be in the 1%.

Comment: Again, this is about researcher awareness.  Good, direct script design is a telltale differentiator between professional and amateur code.  I am not saying this answer is "wrong" -- I am saying it could be less appropriate than `fget()`.  Does it outperform `fget()` on a 5-line file? I don't know, maybe.  As a real-life corollary, if you wanted to eat 3 peanuts, you wouldn't open up a new bag, dump the entire bag into a bowl, then pick out 3 peanuts.  You'd more sensibly just shake 3 peanuts out of the bag into your hand.

Comment: I've added a qualifier to the answer