# How do i read first 5 lines in php?

Tags: php, file

I am trying to read the first 5 line code-block in txt file, please how do i do this

I have this php code to get only the first line

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$f = fopen($file, 'r');
$line = fgets($f);
    while (($line = fgets( $f)) !== false) {
            for ($list = 1; $list < 6; $list++){
                $codeline= htmlentities($line );
            }
        }   
fclose($f); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for ($x = 1; $x < 6; $x++) {
    $line = fgets($f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple:

```
<?php
$file_data = array_slice(file('file.txt'), 0, 5);
print_r($file_data);
```

source: [get the first 3 lines of a text file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121329/get-the-first-3-lines-of-a-text-file-in-php/28121382#28121382) from @paul-denisevich

Comment: This _technically_ works, however, it will load the entire file into memory. If the file is say, 1GB, this would not be ideal.

Comment: And it gets 3 not 5, just sayn.

Comment: [How about giving credit to the author?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28121382/1790644)

Answer (score 0):

To open and read a file line by line:

```
$file = fopen( "/path/to/file.txt", "r" );

$index=0;
while ((( $line = fgets( $file )) !== false) && ( $index++ < 5 )) {

    echo $line;
}

fclose( $file );
```

Here, I am initializing a variable `index` to *0*.

In the while loop, we will use `fgets` to read the next line of the file, and assign it to the variable `line`. We will also check that the value of `index` is less then 5, our desired line count, in addition to incrementing the value of the index, after we have read the line.

Once the value of index has reached > 5, the loop will exit, and the file stream will be closed.

The advantage of using [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) over something like [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), is that the latter will load the entire contents of the file into memory - even if you do not plan on using the whole thing.

With a [multi line file](https://www.mclarkdev.com/test/example.txt), [the above code](https://www.mclarkdev.com/test/file.php) will print out the first five lines.

> This is a multi line

Comment: my problem is `doSomethingWith` am new in php

Comment: That is just a function name that I have created, this is where you will preform whatever you need to do with each line. I have added in the counter as well.

Comment: Can you explain `what` is not working? Any errors? Give me 5 to try it out on a webserver - this was typed up from memory.

Comment: Does the user running the webserver, `apache`, have permission to open the file?

Comment: Is not showing error it only show the fifth line in the file but i want it to print 1 to 5 only

Comment: `it only show the fifth line` - what have you changed for the function? I have edited the above to just `echo` the line. There are two links now, one to a multi line file that I am using to test, and one to the PHP code that I have posted. It appears to work as I would expect.

Comment: is not working for me i don't know what the problem is but what should i do now your example is working should i mark as accep?

Comment: I am sorry that it is not working, I would like for it to before you accept. Is the code posted in your question completely up to date? If not, can you update it and we can work trough it. [This is the code as it exists on my server.](https://www.mclarkdev.com/test/file.notphp).