# How can I loop through a large array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I created an array from a very large text file with more than 10.000 entries. This is how my textfile is formatted:

```
1232.cat=Fred
1232.age=13
1232.size=44
1232.food=chicken
1233.cat=Moe
1233.age=4
1233.size=23
1233.food=fish
```

This is my `$animals` array:

```
 array(9435) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["number"]=>
    string(4) "1232"
    ["cat"]=>
    string(4) "Fred"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "13"
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["food"]=>
    string(7) "chicken"
   }
   ...(and so on)
```

I want to do various checks, for example if for each number `cat` exists.

```
    foreach($animals as $row) {
        if(empty($row['cat'])){
        echo "cat is missing in number: ".$row["number"];
       } 
    }
```

This is working very well for textfiles with around 3000 entries. But for larger files I cannot get any results. 
So my question is, what can I do. Obviously I cannot loop through very large arrays. But what is my alternative?

Comment: not sure, but would the problem lies in `set_time_limit` also ?? http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: You could [read the file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php) instead of the whole file. Given that you don't run out of memory when you read the whole file, you can use a [generator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) and yield only what you need. Worth mentioning, @Andrew and myself are 2 different people.

Comment: @Andrew just notice lol

Comment: There is a limit how large files PHP can read. As @Andrew said, you can read the file partially line by line!]

Comment: @Andrew We should enter a thread and have 2 different opinions on something. That way people will think somebody is arguing with himself. :D

Comment: @Andrew lol, I was thinking the same thing and it becomes an enormous infinite of loop

Comment: @Andrew I tried `set_time_limit(60);` on the beginning of my page and after 54 seconds I got an output! That is really great. Do you know what is the largest time limit I can set?

Comment: @Andrew I will now have a look at line by line

Comment: you can use JudyArray for large data input/output https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/book.judy.php

Comment: @jarla Every time you call `set_time_limit` it will reset the timer so you can think of an reasonable amount of time a single line should have to parse in.

Comment: Have you tried using `array_filter` rather than iterating over your large array? 

Something like `$noCats = array_column(array_filter($arr, function($item) {
    return empty($item['cat']);
}), 'number');` would give you an array of the 'number' fields with an empty 'cat'.