# remove txt file line by line using php

Tags: php

remove txt file line by line using php? have txt file like this

```
.../path/ffdfygfftg_230x260.jpeg
.../path/ttttoooooop_125x340.png
.../path/pppppppffd_450x440.gif
```

i have 70.000 line link image for this.. but this tumbnail size...

normal size link is

```
.../path/ggdfghfdf.jpeg
```

So I am looking for a way to open the text file, reading it line by line and removing start from (_) values while also removing end before dot (.)

posible using php?

Comment: there are lots of options like using regex or substring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php     and then use `unset('full path of that file').`

Comment: Is this question already solved? I don't quite see what you want to do here? What do you want to remove? The numberXnumber from each path?

Answer (score 0):

This will remove everything between the last underscore .

```
$filename = '.../path/ffdfygfftg_230x260.jpeg';
$new_filename = preg_replace('/_[^_.]*\./', '.', $filename);
echo $new_filename;
```

**Output**

```
.../path/ffdfygfftg.jpeg
```

Comment: how to open file.txt , remove, and seve it file.txt, This link is located in a txt file

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much memory usage matters, the following snippet is a simple way to alter every line in the text file. The downside of this method is that the entire text file will be loaded in memory before it is altered.

```
    $filecontents = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt'); //Load the file contents
    $newcontent = preg_replace('/(_)(.*)(\.)(.*)/' '.${4}', $filecontents); //Use a regular expression to alter the file contents. The replacement (.${4}) adds the . and the file extension back into the line.
    file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', $newcontent);
```

To make it more memory efficient, look into the [fgets()](http://php.net/fgets) function, and apply it with the same regular expression

Comment: what is the function of (.${4}) ?

Comment: Did you read the comment on the line where it is used? It's explained there. The . is just a dot. The ${4} is the 4th match in the regular expression (so the file extension). Thus this adds .<file_ext> back into the line.

Comment: for all file extention , like .png, jpg, gif , jpeg, etc ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, even it was an extension like .asdf, this is a general solution, if your path contains just 1 underscore.

Comment: whether it function ${4} will calculate the letter of jpeg (4 char) ? , if true ,how about png (3 char) or gif ?

Comment: No, that's false. The trick is in the '/(_)(.*)(\.)(.*)/' part. There are 4 sets of brackets. The last bracket (.*) matches everything after the dot (this is the file extension). Next, the ${4} references the last bracket (.*), which is the file extension. So wheter it is 2, 3, or 30 characters long, it doesn't matter.

Comment: i try it but error ..
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.${4}'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/path/public_html/path/apps/replc/rep.php on line 4