# Trouble reading from txt file

Tags: php

This is a specific problem I got and can't understand what I did wrong. Don't flag this question again because of "possible duplicate" because **I KNOW** how to open and print out a file. This is not what I'm asking for.

This is my txt file:

```
onceagain|Tristam - Once Again.mp3|gh|Tristam|Once Again;
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS;
blue|Au5 Fractal - Blue.mp3|drumstep|Au5 & Fractal|Blue;
airplanes|B.O.B - Airplanes (Feint Remix).mp3|dnb|B.O.B.|Airplanes (Feint Remix);
sea|Camellia - Flying in the Flow of Deep-Sea.mp3|dubstep|Camellia|Flying in the Flow of Deep-Sea;
onslaught|CENOB1TE - Onslaught.mp3|dubstep|CENOB1TE|Onslaught;
snakeeyes|Feint - Snake Eyes (feat. CoMa).mp3|drumstep|Feint|Snake Eyes (feat. CoMa);
wontbealone|Feint - We Won't Be Alone (feat. Laura Brehm).mp3|dnb|Feint|We Won't Be Alone (feat. Laura Brehm);
vine|Tristam - The Vine.mp3|drumstep|Tristam|The Vine;
frameofmind|Tristam & Braken - Frame of Mind.mp3|dnb|Tristam & Braken|Frame of Mind;
heist|Noisestorm - Heist.mp3|trap|Noisestorm|Heist;
```

I could print out everthing, but I want to print them out using `for` loop, because I will be puting everything in seperate variables later:

```
$myfile = fopen("songs.txt", "r");
$songs = fread($myfile,filesize("songs.txt"));
$lines = count(file("songs.txt")) - 1;

for ($x = 0;  $x <= $lines; $x++) {
    echo strtok($songs, ";");
    $songs = strstr($songs, ';');
}
```

Unfortunately, this is what output i recieve:

```
onceagain|Tristam - Once Again.mp3|gh|Tristam|Once Again
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS
```

I need this to be fixed.

Comment: Why are you doing `strtok()` with a `;`.... there isn't a `;` anywhere in the file that you've shown.... perhaps you meant to use `|` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line by line in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

Comment: @MarkBaker - There is a `;` at the end of every line

Comment: Well far easier to read each line, trim() the trailing `;` and the use str_getcsv() to split on the `|`

Comment: @MarkBaker Still not what I'm looking for. I want to split whole file into arrays. For example: http://pastie.org/private/i64yngntvzgxwe14mjucg#1

Comment: And which part of what I suggested doesn't split the whole file into arrays? And even better, my suggestion doesn't involve reading the entire file into memory twice.... or of using the same variable name for the contents of the entire file, and for a single line of that file

Comment: @MarkBaker I see no use for trim() here

Comment: @Kajcioch - so what do you want to do with the `;` at the end of each line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109327/discussion-between-kajcioch-and-mark-baker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use `explode()` to break up your file. Explode separates by a delimiter, and then puts the data into an array. You can then iterate over this array and print out the data.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("songs.txt", "r");
$songs = fread($myfile,filesize("songs.txt"));
$lines = count(file("songs.txt")) - 1;

$songs = explode(";",$songs);

for ($x = 0;  $x <= $lines; $x++) {
    echo $songs[$x]."<br>";
}
```

Using original solution:

Your problem comes because you do not remove the semicolon at the end. When `strstr()` is used, the needle is left in the result. On your pass, you split correctly, get the song and print it, and then when you use `strstr()` you remove the first song, leaving you with:

```
;
seksikeks|AContrari - SEKS I KEKS.mp3|dubstep|AContrari|SEKS I KEKS;
blue|Au5 Fractal - Blue.mp3|drumstep|Au5 & Fractal|Blue;
...
```

Then on the next pass you get the next song, seksikeks, and print it, however when you use `strstr()` it finds the delimiter as the first character and so does not remove anything. This is why it continues to print because the line is not being removed, and the variable `$songs` stays as it is shown above.

The code below fixes the issue: By removing first the song, and then the semicolon, you can iterate properly.

```
$myfile = fopen("songs.txt", "r");
$songs = fread($myfile,filesize("songs.txt"));
$lines = count(file("songs.txt")) - 1;

for ($x = 0;  $x <= $lines; $x++) {
    $song = strtok($songs, ";");
    echo $song;
    $songs = strstr($songs, $song);
    $songs = strstr($songs, ';');
}
```

Here is also the code for what you have asked for in the comments:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("songs.txt", "r");
$songs = fread($myfile,filesize("songs.txt"));
$lines = count(file("songs.txt")) - 1;

$songs = explode(";",$songs);

$result = array();

for ($x = 0;  $x <= $lines; $x++) {
    $song = explode('|',$songs[$x]);
    $songHandle = $song[0]; // First item is array item name
    $songArray = array(); // Create an array and assign properties to it
    $songArray['file'] = $song[1]; 
    $songArray['genre'] = $song[2];
    $songArray['artist'] = $song[3];
    $songArray['title'] = $song[4];
    $result[$songHandle] = $songArray; // Add our array to the the result
}

var_dump($result); // Show our result
```

Comment: I will need to put those into arrays later. For example: http://pastie.org/private/i64yngntvzgxwe14mjucg#1 Maybe you could pass me a better solution for that?

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for a really good explanation and a fixed code!

Comment: No problem. I've also solved your comment issue in the recent edit