# Formatting and converting dates and time

Tags: bash, unix, awk, gawk

I have a **Very large (13 GiB)** csv file (3856321 rows and 1698) where as expected some of the dates are differently formated. The file looks like ::

```
2013/01/08 2:11:30 AM,abdc,good time ...
2015/12/28 8:19:30 PM,abdc,good time ...
2/15/2016 10:46:30 AM,kdafh,almost as good ...
12/13/2014 10:46:00 PM,asjhdk,not that good ...
02-Jan-2014,bad time,good time ...
1/1/2015,nomiss time,boy ...
10/15/2016 17:08:30,bad,boy ...
```

I want to convert it to a same time format and required output is ::

```
1/8/2013 2:11:30,abdc,good time
12/28/2015 20:19:30,abdc,good time
2/15/2016 10:46:30,kdafh,almost as good
12/13/2014 22:46:00,asjhdk,not that good
1/2/2014 00:00:00,bad time,good time
1/1/2015 00:00:00,nomiss time,boy
10/15/2016 17:08:30,bad,boy
```

I managed to format the time using the following scripts

```
 awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{split($1,a," "); 
 if(a[3]=="PM") 
 {  split(a[2],b,":"); 
    b[1]=b[1]+12    
    a[2]=b[1]":"b[2]":"b[3]
 };
 if(a[2]=="")
 {
        a[2]="00:00:00"
 }
tmp=a[1];
# tmp2=system("date -d `tmp` +%m/%d/%Y");
# print tmp2
$1=tmp" "a[2]
 }1' time_input.csv
```

I borrowed the idea of formatting dates from question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177888/how-to-convert-date-format-in-file
which is commented out in the second last line. However, this does not work in my case. I get an error

```
date: invalid date ‘+%m/%d/%Y’
```

Is there an easier and better way to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Python, using the `dateutils` and `csv` modules:

```
import dateutil.parser as parser
import csv

with open('time_input.csv', 'rb') as inputfile, open('time_output.csv', 'w') as outputfile:

  reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=',')
  writer = csv.writer(outputfile)

  for row in reader:
    row[0] = parser.parse(row[0]).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    writer.writerow(row)
```

The result is output to  `time_output.csv` file.

Answer (score 1):

Awk sure is one great way of doing it but since it's really early morning here I don't like to think about all those `if`s so here is one in php, since it's got a really nice `strtotime` function:

```
$ cat program.php
<?php
  $handle = fopen("file", "r");
  if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
      // process the line read.

      $arr = explode(",", $line, 2);                     
      echo date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime($arr[0])), ",", $arr[1];

    }
    fclose($handle);
  } else {
  // error opening the file.
}
```

Run it:

```
$ php -f program.php
01/08/2013 02:11:30,abdc,good time
12/28/2015 20:19:30,abdc,good time
02/15/2016 10:46:30,kdafh,almost as good
12/13/2014 22:46:00,asjhdk,not that good
01/02/2014 00:00:00,bad time,good time
01/01/2015 00:00:00,nomiss time,boy
10/15/2016 17:08:30,bad,boy
```

The read line by line loop comes from here: [How to read a file line by line in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php). I only added lines with `explode` and `strtotime`.

The `explode` splits the line to pieces by the first `,` and stores them to array `$arr`. `strtotime` function is applied to the first element `$arr[0]`. `$arr[1]` is later outputed as-is.

Comment: Thanks! Although it does what I asked for, I am accepting above python example because that seemed a tad faster for larger files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below awk command -

> Input

```
vipin@kali:~$ cat kk.txt
2013/01/08 2:11:30 AM,abdc,good time
2015/12/28 8:19:30 PM,abdc,good time
2/15/2016 10:46:30 AM,kdafh,almost as good
12/13/2014 10:46:00 PM,asjhdk,not that good
02-Jan-2014,bad time,good time
1/1/2015,nomiss time,boy
10/15/2016 17:08:30,bad,boy
```

> filtering -

```
vipin@kali:~$  awk -F"," '{split($1,a," "); printf ("%s,%s,%s",$2,$3,",");system("date -d \""a[1]" "a[2]"\" +\"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S\"")}'  kk.txt
abdc,good time,,01/08/2013 02:11:30
abdc,good time,,12/28/2015 08:19:30
kdafh,almost as good,,02/15/2016 10:46:30
asjhdk,not that good,,12/13/2014 10:46:00
bad time,good time,,01/02/2014 00:00:00
nomiss time,boy,,01/01/2015 00:00:00
bad,boy,,10/15/2016 17:08:30
```

> Move the filtered output to file kk.txt2

```
vipin@kali:~$  awk -F"," '{split($1,a," "); printf ("%s,%s,%s",$2,$3,",");system("date -d \""a[1]" "a[2]"\" +\"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S\"")}'  kk.txt > kk.txt2
```

> Output

```
vipin@kali:~$ awk -F"," '{print $NF,$1,$2}' OFS="," kk.txt2
01/08/2013 02:11:30,abdc,good time
12/28/2015 08:19:30,abdc,good time
02/15/2016 10:46:30,kdafh,almost as good
12/13/2014 10:46:00,asjhdk,not that good
01/02/2014 00:00:00,bad time,good time
01/01/2015 00:00:00,nomiss time,boy
10/15/2016 17:08:30,bad,boy
```

> Explanation -

Use `Split` function on column 1 and put it in a and then use `system` function of awk to format the date as per our need.

I can print the output in order but it was printing a leading zero so i am printing formatted date in last column that is why i am moving the data in another file.
and finally you can print the column in your order.

Comment: Thanks! Since I had multiple columns (>1500, which I didn't mention in my question, Apologies ). This print wouldn't work very well but I got the idea of using date in awk with dynamic variables. However, since the python idea above was easier, I am accepting tha