# PHP reading big txt file, memory solution

Tags: php, file, text

I have a big text file (like 10.000 row). Im trying to fix memory problems. I'm using this code, to read every row from my text file.

```
$handle = fopen("votes.txt", "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) 
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        echo $buffer."</br>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

When i read the file, is taking too much time, and i guess taking too much memory. Any solution to reading this file line by line. Important: i dont want to read all rows at the same time, i want to read line by line.

Comment: If all you're doing is reading/displaying; then use `readfile()` for the most efficient method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line by line in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

Comment: 10000 rows, It isn't a big file, I doubt memory is an issue (especially since the buffer is limited to 4096). I think the problem comes from another thing.

Comment: maybe its now not a big file, but later can be big and i dont want to rewrite my code, if the file is going to bigger

Comment: @RolandFaragó: in this case use a database and not a file.