# how can I get the image names that are inside a text file with php?

Tags: php

Like always, I am having issues doing this. So, I have been able to extract images from folders using php, but since it was taking too long to do that, I decided to just extract the names from a text file and then do a while loop and echo the list of results. For example I have a file called, "cats.txt" and inside the data looks like this.

```
Kitten1.jpg
Kitten2.jpg
Kitten3.jpg
```

I could easily use an sql or json table to do this, but I am not allowed. So, I only have this.

Now, I have tried doing this, but I get an error.

--- PHP CODE ---

```
$data = file ("path/to/the/file/cats.txt");
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($data); i++){
 $images = '<img src="/kittens/t/$i">';
}

$CatLife = '
Images of our kittens:<br>

'.$images.'


';
```

I would really appreciate the help. I am not sure of what the error is, since the page doesn't tell me anything. It just doesn't load.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php

Comment: Problem is you are making an images string, storing your counter as file name, and clobbering `$images` on each iteration.  You want `$data[$i]`, or to use a foreach, as `$data` is an array of lines from your file.  You need to concat. your cats!

Comment: Progrock yeah, I just did something similar. '.$data[$i].' and now it works. I also had to specify the full path of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$fp = fopen('path/to/the/file/cats.txt', 'r');
$images = '';
while(!feof($fp)) {
     $row = fgets($fp);
     $images .= '<img src="/kittens/t/'.$row.'">';
}
fclose($fp);

$CatLife = "Images of our kittens:<br>$images";
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Get used to `foreach()`.  Much easier.  Also note that variables like `$file` in your `img` tag don't get interpreted in single quotes. I use an array and then implode it:

```
$data = file ("path/to/the/file/cats.txt");
foreach($data as $file) {
    $images[] = '<img src="/kittens/t/'.$file.'">';
}

$CatLife = '
Images of our kittens:<br>

'.implode($images).'


';
```

You could also just use `$images .= '<img src="/kittens/t/$file">';` to concatenate and not need to implode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the glob php function instead of parsing your txt file.

```
foreach (glob("path/to/the/file/Kitten*.jpg") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $data = file ("path/to/the/file/cats.txt");
    $images = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($data); i++){
         $images .= '<img src="/kittens/t/$i">');
    }

    $CatLife = 'Images of our kittens:<br>'.$images.'';
    echo $CatLife;
```

Try this, it stores each image tag into a string and echos it to the page.

Comment: Outputs something like: `Images of our kittens:<br><img src="/kittens/t/0"><img src="/kittens/t/1">` and so on.