# How to update url references that change every day on the drop down menu?

Tags: php, html

Every day, you download a txt file that contains the url and then I have to manually update the index.html file of a pulldown menu. Is there a way to automatically update the url without having to edit the index file? This is an example of how and dialed the file.txt that drain each day and that below a portion of the index file code.

Text1, Text2, and Text3 to remain unchanged, while the url change daily

**File_url.txt**

```
<a href='http://example.com/update1/day1.txt'>text1</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/update2/day1.txt'>text2</a><br/> 
<a href='http://example.com/update3/day1.txt'>text3</a><br/>
```

in the index file, the url are inserted so

**File index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>



<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>CSS DropDown Menu</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/simple.css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>



<div id="drop-menu">

<ul id="menu">

  <li><a href="http://example.com/home.php"target="principale" >Home</a></li>

<ul>

</ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="#"target="principale" >Extra</a>

<ul>
<li><a href='http://example.com/update1/day1.txt'target="principale">text1</a><br/></li>
<li><a href='http://example.com/update2/day1.txt'target="principale">text2</a><br/></li>
<li><a href='http://example.com/update3/day1.txt'target="principale">text3</a><br/></li>

</ul>

 </li>

 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

</ul>

</div>

<iframe name="principale" src="http://example.com/home.php" marginheight="50" height="800" width="100%" allowfullscreen = "true" ></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

For example, the next day I can find

**File_url.txt**

```
<a href='http://example.com/update1/day2.txt'>text1</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/update2/day2.txt'>text2</a><br/> 
<a href='http://example.com/update3/day2.txt'>text3</a><br/>
```

Is there a way to automatically update the reference Url perhaps using Text1, Text2, and Text3 that never change?

Comment: Where is the code that writes the index.html?  Why not stick that inside an index.php and make that the index file (rather than static index.html).  Read File_url.txt directly and dynamically generate your pulldown.

Comment: I edited the post, now the index.html / index.php file is complete

Comment: Can you remove the tag php as this question no longer relates to php nor does the answer chosen reflect php. Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use server side script like PHP for example, you can use function like `readfile()` function to read the entire file then use `foreach` function to iterate over it's rows and render the items to your html.

But, if you don't use server side script at once, I think you can expose the txt file so it can be accessed via URL, for example `localhost/file_url.txt` then use javascript ajax function to get it's content from URL and render them into your HTML.

Here's the code using javascript to get the content of you file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>CSS DropDown Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/simple.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="drop-menu">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li><a href="http://example.com/home.php"target="principale" >Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"target="principale" >Extra</a></li>
        <ul>
        <ul id="dynamic-menu">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <iframe name="principale" src="http://example.com/home.php" marginheight="50" height="800" width="100%" allowfullscreen = "true" ></iframe>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var menuRequest = $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:30001/file_url.txt'
            });

            menuRequest.done(function(data, status, xhr) {
                var dynamicMenuWrapper = $('#dynamic-menu');
                dynamicMenuWrapper.html(data);
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*note: remember to make your txt file accessible by pointing it to a specific URL

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your edit, but it seems it does not work, in fact, under the extras menu, I can not find any link.

Comment: Have you placed id="dynamic-menu" to element where you wanna place your dynamic menus? here the logic of the script: 1. place an `id` to html element where you wanna place the dynamic menus, in my example I placed it inside `<ul id="dynamic-menu">`, 2. get list of menu using ajax request from your file, 3. manipulate the html using javascript by appending list of menu you've got into html element which has id="dynamic-menu".

Comment: Sorry, how do you run your html script?  By using web server such as XAMPP, etc or just open it directly from your file's directory?

Comment: Manually editing File_url.txt I knew it would work, but I have to change it by editing the file. `<li><a href="http://example.com/home.php"target="principale" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href=""principale" >Extra</a>

<ul>
<li><a href='http://example.com/update1/day1.txt'>text1</a><br/></li>
</li><a href='http://example.com/update2/day1.txt'>text2</a><br/></li> 
</li><a href='http://example.com/update3/day1.txt'>text3</a><br/></li>`
I find the links under the extras menu and it works, how I can directly add the changes before reading each string from the file

Comment: did you get your problem solved yet? Sorry for not responding for a while hehe

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to solve this, One is to itterate over the file_url.txt  in index.html( index.php? )
You could  follow this example in the [How to read a file line by line in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

Keep in mind 'file_url.txt' would be the path to where the file is located.
Chances are if your structure is like this.

- root dir

  - index.php
  - file_url.txt

You would want "./file_url.txt"

```
    ...  
    <li><a href="#"target="principale" >Extra</a>

      <ul>
          <?php if ($file = fopen("./file_url.txt", "r")) {
            while(!feof($file)) {
              $line = fgets($file);
              # do same stuff with the $line
                echo sprintf(
                  '<li>%s</li>',
                  $line
                );
            }
            fclose($file);
          } ?> 
     </ul>
 </li>

 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 ...
```

Otherwise, I believe javascript ( jQuery ) would have to be the way to go.

Comment: how should I edit the index.html file you can take an example, I'm currently running everything under localhost, are very novice with programming, cmq thank you for your answers

Comment: Added some basic structuring for your use. As you can see most people are suggesting to use client side scripting. Not sure that is the way you want to go as you lose SEO in some instances or if javcascript is turned off