# Replace each instance of a character in a string with the first number of the string in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

This is probably a very obscure reqeust but I have 6,000+ lines that look like this..

```
#1234 - 1,9
#5678 - 7,10,23
```

I need to take the #1234 (user id) and pair it with each number in the string to make new strings, i.e.

```
#1234 - 1
#1234 - 9
#5678 - 7
#5678 - 10
#5678 - 23
```

How can this be done? The lines all vary in how many numbers/commas are in the strings

Comment: what have you tried? are you familiar with any programming language?

Comment: I'm familiar with HTML and PHP, I've dabble with Regex but nothing this complicated. I tried one regex thing that didn't work, but now I can't track it down. I've mostly been trying to do it inline with the multiple cursor. I was able to extrapolate how many numbers or in each line, but I realized I don't know how i can make that useful.

Comment: regex and html aren't programming languages, so i think your best bet will be to use php. here are some resources toget you started: https://www.google.com.sg/amp/s/davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete/amp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php . The idea is to read the file line by line; for each line you explode (split) by hyphen to get user and the numbers, then split the numbers by comma. then you write these values to a new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To user regex replace, you can repeat this search and replace until no more remain:

Search for:

```
^((#[0-9]+ - )[0-9,]+),([0-9]+)$
```

and replace with

```
$1\n$2$3
```

Comment: I figured out a different solution but hank you for your response NetMage however when I tried it, I got...

#1234 - 1\n#1234 - 9
#5678 - 7,10\n#5678 - 23

Comment: I should add that I ran it twice and the other comma doesn't get replaced

Comment: I lied, it wasn't working on an online regex that has been working better because of there being so many lines, but I tried it in sublime text and it works! You're a saint and a scholar, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If python is an option, for this *specific* case this code should work:

```
from re import findall

input = """#1234 - 1,9
#5678 - 7,10,23"""
regexStr = "\d+"
for line in input.split('\n'):
    matches = findall(regexStr, line)
    for i in range(1, len(matches)):
        print("#" + matches[0] + " - " + matches[i])
```

output:

```
#1234 - 1
#1234 - 9
#5678 - 7
#5678 - 10
#5678 - 23
```