# How to get string from a file using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, text-files

Ok so I have a txt file (mytxt.txt)

Content inside is saved like this

```
name (username)
name (username)
```

And I'm trying to get these lines and put them in a HTML `<li>` element but I can't figure out how

What im trying to do is to get every line of the document to echo in a difrent `<li>` HTML element

Comment: Here is a link to the [PHP Manual, filesystem section](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) The manual is always a good place to start

Comment: Use the `file()` function to read a file into an array of strings. Each line is an element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line by line in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a file with php like this:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("mytxt.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while( !feof( $myfile ) ) {
?> <li> <?php echo fgets($myfile); ?> </li>
<?php
}

fclose($myfile);
?>
```

just place this inside the element that you want the info to echo into.

Comment: I want every line of the document to echo in a difrent <li> element

Comment: If that worked for you can you please mark as answer?