# read file from a server http url in php

Tags: php

i want to print/echo a file that's save on my server and have a specific URL and try this below code to read

```
$lines = file($files['file_path']);
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
   echo htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
```

but it returned the following error :

```
file(http://myweburl/uploads/files/1506514901_txt.txt): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

and i also try fgets with fopen function that return same error

i also follow [How to read a file line by line in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php) but don't get any solutions

while above function is working on localhost but not server

please help

Comment: you can't access file by http://myweburl/uploads/files/1506514901_txt.txt this path you need to get the path by directory location

Comment: If your myweburl folder is directly on next level to public_html try public_html/path_without_http

Comment: great it work and thanks

Comment: but can you explain me why we can't access the http url

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable :

```
allow_url_fopen = on
```

**in php.ini file on your server**