# file_get_contents or alternative to extract the first x lines

Tags: php

I would like to extract the first x lines of an html page
I know that I can extract the amount of characters with something like this:

```
file_get_contents('http://xx.xxx.158.239/fin.html' , NULL, NULL, 0, 125);
```

but what about lines ? like to extract the text from line 1 to line 4? is that possible ?

Comment: What constitutes a new line in your use case? An actual line break in the file, html line break tags in the code or something else?

Comment: Got an example snip from a file you will be trying in the right format? fopen and reading by line will work if its a standard newline format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line by line in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

Comment: @ miknik line break tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the file using dedicated method calls instead of the one-for-all `file_get_contents()`:

```
$fp = fopen('my/file/name', 'r');
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    if (feof($fp)) {
        echo 'EOF reached';
        break;
    }
    echo fgets($fp);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little code snippet that you might find useful:

```
$file = 'http://xx.xxx.158.239/fin.html';  // remote or local file
$lines = 3; // how many lines do you want?
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $contents = @file_get_contents($file); // suppress errors, esp. for remote files
    $head = implode("\n", array_slice(explode("\n", $contents), 0, $lines));
} else {
    $head = 'File does not exist';
}
echo $head;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) on a File- or URL-Handle created by [fopen](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to load the content into an array and read only the relevant lines.

To get the content line by line in a loop, you can use [fgets](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).