# How to compare dates from a read .txt to current date?

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a code for daily birthdays, those birthdays are on a .txt with a Y-m-d date and the name of the person, but I don't know how  to compare the .txt dates with the current date and print the person's name.

That's what I started

```
$current = date("Y-m-d");
$content = fopen("content.txt", "r");
while (!feof($content)){
    $linha  = fgets($content);  
    echo $linha. "<br>";
}
```

That's the .txt content:

```
2017-12-13  ;   teste

2017-12-13  ;   teste

2017-12-15  ;   teste

2017-12-15  ;   teste
```

Comment: use a database!

Comment: There's any other way? I really don't want to use a db.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a database? Yes, you can use a filesystem but that's just like a database with none of the advantages and lots of extra risks

Comment: Using two .txt I can do the comparison, but only with the last lines of the .txt, I'm trying to compare all lines now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php