# How to count lines of 9 GB file in php

Tags: php

I have 9 GB MSSQL file. I want to count lines of the file.
I add the following code:

```
$lines = file('db.sql');
echo count($lines);
```

I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 398458880) (tried to allocate 396361752 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\import\read-line-by-line.php on line 3

Comment: Clearly you can't load the entire 9GB file into memory all at once. Stop trying to do so. If you want to count lines, read the file line by line and increment a counter after each line is read.

Comment: its require 9GB memory?

Comment: @JavedIqbal Yes, if you open a 9 GB file you'll need at least that 9 GBs available. Read it in chunks though and you'll be fine, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: use iterator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line

Answer (score 2):

You should either increase the max_memory_limit in php.ini

or you could use the following if you are using Linux. Linux provides the most robust algorithm in counting lines.

```
$output = shell_exec('wc -l /dir/db.sql');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Windows version

```
$output = shell_exec('find /v /c "" C:\filename.ext');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Comment: My OS is windows 10

Comment: try the windows version find /v /c "" filename.ext

Comment: it works 
---------- C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\IMPORT\test.SQL: 5707419
  .5707419 are no of lines?

Comment: Good answer will helped me too @Wils