# I am unsure what kind of loop to use in php

Tags: php

I am newer to PHP and I am able to get the desired output but I am doing it one index position at a time. I am returning data from a .txt file and I need to insert this data into an HTML table I am creating using PHP. BUT FIRST I need to be able to get the same output without typing out every index position. I tried to use a forloop but it kept outputting only one line.
I manually outputted the lines from the file and it works. What loop in PHP would be best to achieve the same results and output these elements? IMPORTANT, as is I am able to sort and rsort (I want to be able to do this so if it can be implemented in the loop that would be awesome) any help is more than I have right now.

PHP

```
$books = array();

 if ($fp)
{
    while(true)
    {
        $lines_in_file = count(file($filename));
        $line = fgets($fp); 

        if (feof($fp))
        {
            break;
        }
  $line_ctr++;

list($title, $author, $pubdate, $isbn) = explode('*', $line);

    $new_line = explode('*', $line);

    for($ii= 1; $ii <= $lines_in_file; $ii++){
        $lines = fgets($fp); //Read each line
        $member = trim($lines);
        array_push($books, $member);   
    }

    //This foreach only brings back the first like in the txt file, why?
 $cntr = 0;

    foreach($books as $element){
        $cntr++;
        $table .= "<tr>";
        $table .= "<td>".$title."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$author."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$pubdate."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$pubdate."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$isbn."</td>";
        $table .= "</tr>\n";  //added newline
        echo $element;
    }

  //sort($books);
   // rsort($books);
    echo $books[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[1];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[2];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[3];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[4];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[5];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[6];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[7];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[8];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[9];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[10];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[11];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[12];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[13];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[14];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[15];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[16];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $books[17];

}//END WHILE LOOP
fclose($fp ); //Close file
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a large file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line)

Comment: @ IdontDownVote, 1. Thank you for your genuine answer. 2. Would you be able to demonstrate the forloop and integrate an HTML table as well?

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: When I run my code it is only bringing back the first line of the text file. Any ideas why? I used a foreach loop.

Comment: @mike32, Yes sir, I edited my code and added a foreach loop but for some reason it is only bringing back the first like of my .txt file over and over again instead of populating my table with each line in the .txt file. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to make a few guesses here but i  believe the file is going to look like:

```
title*author*pubdate*isbn
title*author*pubdate*isbn
title*author*pubdate*isb
```

if this is wrong, let me know

as long as the fie is not to large read it in to an array:

```
$book_array=file('book_file.txt');
//print_r($book_array); //is it an array of the books, one book per array key
```

now to separate each line:

```
foreach($book_array as $line){

    $line_sep=explode('*',$line);

//    with no sorting option you could just echo inside the loop
  //if you want to keep sorting options we have to keep the separated lines

    $new_book_array[]=$line_sep;
}

unset($book_array);//free up memory if needed
//print_r($new_book_array);//is it a multi-d array, book then the 4 elements
```

to sort our new multidimensoanl array:

```
usort($new_book_array, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['0'], $b['0']);;
}); //this sorts on key 0 in your case title:

//print_r($new_book_array); // has it sorted properly
```

for display:
loop again

```
echo '<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Pub Date</th><th>ISBN</th></tr>';

foreach($new_book_array as $book){
//print_r($book);  //is it each indervidual book array with 4 elements
      echo '<tr><td>'.$book[0].'</td><td>'.$book[1].'</td><td>'.$book[2].'</td><td>'.$book[3].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: only difference is title*author*pubdate*isbn*   ////// in my file the lines have an extra * at the end.

Comment: wont matter, you will just get an empty empty array key pair

Comment: On this line ( return $a['0'] - $b['0'];) I got the following error: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Comment: ah yes, my bad .. fixed

Comment: This works almost perfectly, one last thing. I have a fully populated table but every row returned is the same book.

Comment: works as expected here: https://ideone.com/mFLxd6 are you sure nothing has been changed

Comment: I will double check my code, you are awesome, thank you.

Comment: added some debugging code and notes (start at the top and just uncomment one at at a time) for you, let me know if still stuck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180489/discussion-between-wca-and-idontdownvote).