# Search for text in a 5GB+ file then get whole line

Tags: php, splfileobject

I want to search for the text `Hello` (example) in a TXT file whose size is 5GB+ then return the whole line.

I've tried using `SplFileObject` but what I know is that the line number is required to use `SplFileObject`, like that:

```
$linenumber = 2094; 
$file = new SplFileObject('myfile.txt');
$file->seek($linenumber-1);
echo $file->current();
```

But as previously mentioned, I want to search for a string then get the whole line, I don't know the line number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13246630/215042) with a simple counter?

Comment: You could read the file line by line with a loop? I think it could be useful to parallelize processes so for example one process read from top to bottom and at the same time another read from the bottom to the top.

Comment: What is the size of the line?
Do you only need the first occurrence, or all the lines containing that searched string?

Comment: @programmer-man - The line is about 100 characters, also there's only one occurrence for the string that I am looking for.

Comment: @AnthonyB - exactly, it will take a lot of time.

Comment: @MatrixCow08 You'll probably need to use several processes at the same time. How many lines has your file?

Comment: @AnthonyB - is multi-threading possible in PHP?

Comment: @RobIII Solution seems like the best approach. You could do something like `exec('grep "Hello" myfile.txt', $return);`

Comment: How often are you going to do this?  Would loading the file to a database be useful?

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
<?php
$needle = 'hello';
$count = 1;
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        $pos = strpos($line, $needle);
        if ($pos !== false) {
            echo $line . PHP_EOL;
            echo "in line: ".$count . PHP_EOL;
            break;
        }
        $count++;
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `break;` line in the `while` loop once the line is found?

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer that I can use. Thanks a lot to @user3783243

**For Linux:**

```
exec('grep "Hello" myfile.txt', $return);
```

**For Windows:**

```
exec('findstr "Hello" "myfile.txt"', $return);
```

Now `$return` should contain the whole line.

***Unfortunately,*** this doesn't work if `exec()` and `system()` functions are disabled by your server administrator in the php.ini file. But for me it works fine.

If someone have a better solution I'd be glad to know it :)