# How to read data in line by by line and data it is separated with tab space

Tags: php, laravel, text-files

I have to read data from the text file in line by line to save to the database.
How do I read the data?

below is sample data from the text file

```
    return-date                 order-id              sku
    2019-01-30T20:17:27+00:00   113-3085323-1960253 GCA-6000KITb
    2019-01-30T20:17:27+00:00   113-3085323-1960253 GCA-6000KITb
```

Comment: _How do I read the data..._ Where is your code that is trying to achieve that? What errors/issues are you facing there?

Comment: Hi there, please provide some code that you have already used to try solve this problem. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial or how-to site, however we can help you to debug your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line chat for how to read line by line

Answer (score 0):

You could use [str_getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.str-getcsv.php) with "\t" (tab character) as the $delimiter.