# PHP: How can we explode a string using a single delimiter repeating multiple times?

Tags: php

I am trying to get data of all transactions from a file which contains multiple transaction data, it happens so that I can get transaction data of one transaction by php explode. So my question is how to explode the data to get multiple transactions data ..

```
$data['file'] = file_get_contents('C:\TSaveBatchDBMessage.txt');
    $data['exp'] = explode('TSaveTransactionMessage',$data['file']);
```

it only gives output for the first transaction data, and one files contains almost dozens of transactions ..

Help appreciated

PS: This file is generated by software and there is no possible count of transactions in the file, they may be 100, 1 or any number in between ..

Comment: Read the file [line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line) and explode as you do now.

Comment: Brother .. the transactions are uncountable sometimes .. because the file is created again and again, if that was not the case .. i would have

Comment: The read the whole file into an array and parse it key by key.

Comment: i tried to run it in a foreach loop and if the value of a key is equal to 'TSaveTransactionMessage', I tried to echo there, but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file as an array, iterate through and process each line...

```
foreach( file('C:\TSaveBatchDBMessage.txt') as $line ){
    $data['exp']=explode( 'TSaveTransactionMessage', $line );

    /* do stuff with array */
}
```

Comment: its not helping because the $data['exp'] is not repeating .. instead it gives only first value ..

Comment: it worked when i put a variable with 0 and incremented it in foreach loop and put that in as $data[variable]. its pretty close to what i need .. thank you

Comment: ok - to continually add to that variable use `$data['exp'][]=explode( 'TSaveTransactionMessage', $line );` instead

Answer (score 0):

First read the file line by line than check its count is grater than 1 use foreach loop else do as you are doing

```
 $data['file'] = file_get_contents('C:\TSaveBatchDBMessage.txt');
    if(sizeof($data['file']) > 1){
    foreach($data['file'] as $file){
    $data['exp'] = explode('TSaveTransactionMessage',$file);
    }
    }else{
     $data['exp'] = explode('TSaveTransactionMessage',$data['file']);
    }
```