# Split text file by line and comma to then update a database, PHP

Tags: php

We are working with a fingerprint scanner for attendance, it generates these kind of text files

```
1,MARCOS,MORENO,12:29,15:58,2020-02-26
2,ALEJANDRO,BASAL,12:05,18:01,2020-02-26
3,CARMEN,MORIA,11:58,17:59,2020-02-26
```

We want to upload it to our site, load the file, split that text into lines and then each line into arrays, to work with them, like so:

```
Array1 ([0] => 1 [1] => MARCOS [2] => MORENO [3] => 12:29 [4] => 15:58 [5] => 2020-02-26)
Array2 ([0] => 2 [1] => ALEJANDRO [2] => BASAL[3] => 12:05 [4] => 18:01 [5] => 2020-02-26)
Array3 ([0] => 3 [1] => CARMEN[2] => MORIA [3] => 11:58 [4] => 17:59 [5] => 2020-02-26)
```

To then load each array into a database. Each [0] going into id, [1] into name, etc. We managed to load and read the file, however we are unsure on how to split the file like we want to, so far our code only splits the full array without taking into account the line breaks, it returns this

```
Array ([0] => 1 [1] => MARCOS [2] => MORENO [3] => 12:29 [4] => 15:58 [5] => 2020-02-26 [6] => 2 [7] => ALEJANDRO [8] => BASAL[9] => 12:05 [10] => 18:01 [11] => 2020-02-26 [12] => 3 [13] => CARMEN[14] => MORIA [15] => 11:58 [16] => 17:59 [17] => 2020-02-26)
```

Each line is an employee and each line will always have the same amount of splits (by commas). Maybe if its not possible to split by line breaks just being able to handle additions will be enough (handle every [0]s with [6]s, [12]s, [18]s and so on together). To then update values in our database.

Our code right now is really simple, just

```
$file= 'attendance/' . '{file}';
$doc=file_get_contents($file);

$line=explode("\n",$doc);
foreach($line as $newline){
    echo '<h3 style="color:#453288">'.$newline.'</h3><br>';
}
```

Comment: try read file line by line using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13246630/2177461 and each line you can use explode by comma , https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: It's definitely possible to do this, but it's difficult to say what changes you need to make to your code to get it working the way you want without seeing it.

Comment: Our code right now it's really simple, just
$file = 'attendance/' . '{file}';
$doc=file_get_contents($file);

$line=explode("\n",$doc);
foreach($line as $newline){
    echo '<h3 style="color:#453288">'.$newline.'</h3><br>';
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try read file line by line using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13246630/2177461 and each line you can use explode by comma , https://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$file = 'attendance/' . '{file}'; 
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        $data = explode(',', $line);
        // $data will have Array1 ([0] => 1 [1] => MARCOS [2] => MORENO [3] => 12:29 [4] => 15:58 [5] => 2020-02-26)
        print_r($data);
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

Note: its **pseudo code** might have syntax errors

Comment: Thank you, it does work, however for some reason the first two lines are combined and it just restarts counting from line three, maybe there's something wrong with the file? I'll check